# What is the meaning of an operator (:>) in a data constructor?

Tags: haskell, constructor

Does anyone know what's the meaning of the ':>' constructor in the following code:

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Haskell the functions whose name consists of alphanumeric characters are prefix by default, and the functions made up from characters like `+`, `>`, `$` etc are infix by default. For example, you can define an infix function like

```
Prelude> let a $%^ b = a + b
Prelude> :t ($%^)
($%^) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Same applies to constructors (**Edit**: as @ChrisTaylor correctly noted, with the limitation that the name of an infix constructor must start with `:`). The line

```
Prelude> data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
```

Means that `:>` is a constructor that takes two arguments:

```
Prelude> :t (:>)
(:>) :: a -> [Rose a] -> Rose a
```

You could as well create a normal-looking constructor as

```
data Rose a = RoseCtr a [Rose a]
```

which would have the same type. In some cases infix functions/constructors are more intuitive and make the code more understandable.

Comment: You should add that infix type constructors must start with : and that you need the TypeOperators language pragma.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: thanks, you are quite right about the colon, but are you sure about the pragma? GHC 7.6.3 does not seem to require it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However I don't get what the operator :> does? Is it a special operator or one created, could I just as well have put :< instead of :>? (what does the operator do?)

Comment: @Skyfe The definition above *creates* the operator, and what it does is, when you apply it to something and a list of Rose of the same something it gives you a Rose somethng.

Comment: @Skyfe: yes, you could have put any sequence of non-alphanumeric characters after the colon, that's a new entity you create.

Comment: Looks like you're right about the pragma. I haven't updated GHC in a while :)

Comment: Why do data constructor operators need to be prefixed with `:`? is there any notational ambiguity?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: I don't really know. I've seen an explanation that it is purely an enforced naming convention to distinguish type constructors from functions, similar as how alphanumeric type constructors must start from a capital letter.